# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-8

My code is working in local but when I uploaded it on cpanel it keeps giving me this error, I don't know whats wrong here, the path to the AuthController.php file is correct stil its unable to locate it. i have cleared cache, routes, config, views, still nothing, I even tried creating a new auth controller and pasted my code in it, still the same error. can anyone help me here?

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController] does not exist. in file /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 811

#0 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(691): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Contro...')
#1 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array, true)
#2 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(637): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array)
#3 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Contro...', Array)
#4 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(253): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Contro...')
#5 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(970): Illuminate\Routing\Route->getController()
#6 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(931): Illuminate\Routing\Route->controllerMiddleware()
#7 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(702): Illuminate\Routing\Route->gatherMiddleware()
#8 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(678): Illuminate\Routing\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#9 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(662): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(628): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#11 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(617): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/logictpt/public_html/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectTrailingSlash.php(26): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): App\Http\Middleware\RedirectTrailingSlash->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#30 /home/logictpt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/logictpt/public_html/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 {main}
```

Comment: Did you dump your composer's autoload file?

Comment: I just did still getting the same error

Comment: I'm running the api on postman, I cleared its cache as well, again same error.

Comment: where did you put this controller, what namespace did you define in it ... what is the class name, what is the filename?

Comment: `App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController.php` this is the controller path

Answer (score 1):

same issue with you
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/target-class-apphttpcontrollersapiauthcontroller-does-not-exist

`App\Http\Controllers\api\Auth\AuthController`

lower case the Api word

i think ubuntu directory is case sensitive, while window not.